# Data stored in UTC timezone in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, timezone-offset

Is it possible to store date time fields in sql server in UTC format and still display them in the local time zone in your tables in SQL Server?

Our source has UTC data which we need to convert to local time zone in SQL Server which creates issues when we do calculations as there is no offset information in SQL Server. Any possible solutions for this?

I am using the below Oracle command to get time related fields and saving them in SQL Server DATETIME.

```
to_char(from_tz (cast(some_datetime as timestamp),'UTC')  at time zone 'Australia/Sydney','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as some_datetime
```

If I do the calculations on dates saved like this, they will be incorrect. So I wanted to save them in UTC in the back-end . But in the tables they need to be visible in the current timezone as UTC doesn't make sense.

Comment: Select as `YourDate AT TIME ZONE 'Some Time Zone'` maybe? Or store them in local time in a `DATETIMEOFFSET`

Comment: What sorts of calculations are you running into issues with? UTC is great insofar as it doesn't experience DST so figuring out how much time elapsed between two timestamps is just `datediff()`. With time zones that do experience DST, you need logic to tell if you've crossed a boundary (or more than one!), you'll need to deal with the "01:30 occurred more than once on this day", etc.

Comment: It is a small matter to convert the UTC to and from local time on the client-side.   So if a transaction was entered at 9AM in New York ... It would be displayed as 6AM in California

Comment: @BenThul I have updated the question. Because back-end isn't UTC, the calculations are done in current time. Can there be a workaround for that?

Comment: Seems like less of a calculation and more of a "change what you know to be a UTC datetime into a string of that same timestamp but in the Australia/Sydney TZ". Is that right?

Comment: @BenThul Yes the command changes it into the Australian time stamp. So when I use these dates, the datetimediff is always wrong. For eg. If order came at 1AM and processed after an hour, the Time changed at 2 AM to 3AM. So the calculation would give the difference as 2 hrs and not 1.

Comment: @BenThul In simple language, I just want the dates to saved in UTC in the table but they display the current time in the tables. SO when the difference is calculated we get the right result. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Right. That was my point in saying that calculations should be done in UTC to avoid any issues with DST. So you really have two issues - "how to do date math?" (do that math on the UTC timestamps) and "how do display the UTC timestamps in the Sydney TZ?" (`select yourColumn at time zone 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' from yourTable`). I would posit that the latter is a job that's better done somewhere other than your very expensive database server, but that's between you and your accounting department.

Comment: @BenThul If we add this (select yourColumn at time zone 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' from yourTable). it would need to be added everytime you query. Is there a setting that can be done so it automatically displays dates for all tables in the current timezone?

Comment: No. You could add a computed column to your table that has that as the definition or a view that either replaces that column in the select list or adds one but there is not to my knowledge anything like what you're describing.

Comment: Thankyou @BenThul That was very helpful. I am working on a solution and post the answer for your input as well.

Comment: @BenThul I created this function
`ALTER function [dbo].[utc_diff](@begin_date DATETIME2,@end_date DATETIME2)  
returns TIME
as begin   
 declare @retdate DATETIME
 
 Select 
@retdate = CAST(DATEADD(s, DATEDIFF(s, @begin_date AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
                       , @end_date AT TIME ZONE 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')  
                       , CAST('2000-01-01' AS DATETIME2(0))) AS TIME)
 
return isnull(@retdate, 0)` I got an error. The datediff function resulted in an overflow message

Comment: Hmm... that's interesting. `datediff` should be able to handle arguments up to max int size. What values are you passing to the function that give you that error? Unrelated, having the return data type be a `time` is odd to me. Why? If I pick the same time of day on two successive (or even distant - so long as their UTC offset is the same), you'll get `00:00:00` as the return.